# VSCode Run -> Start Debugging Python with Launch.json Doesn't Run Anything

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

In Visual Studio Code, After setting up a `launch.json` for Python Flask, I got a file like this:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Flask",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "module": "flask",
        "env": {
            "FLASK_APP": "app.py",
            "FLASK_DEBUG": "1"
        },
        "args": [
            "run",
            "--no-debugger",
            "--no-reload"
        ],
        "jinja": true,
        "justMyCode": true
    },
]
```

But when I try to run my project through the menu <kbd>Run</kbd> → <kbd>Start Debugging</kbd> (<kbd>F5</kbd>), VSCode starts doing something and shows the debug bar (with pause/reload buttons), but a moment later the bar disappears without my projecting running at all, without even showing a terminal, printing logs, or giving any error message. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen when the Python version of your project (e.g. used by `venv`) is no longer supported by the Python debugger installed as a VSCode Extension. For example, [Python 3.6 stopped being supported by the extension mid 2022](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/19441), so if your project still uses Python 3.6, the latest version of the debugger will silently not work.

So there are two ways to fix: either you update Python to a supported version (recommended), or if that's not possible then you can try downgrading the extension down to a version that still supports your outdated Python version.

To downgrade: click on Extensions (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+X</kbd>), search for Python, click the options cog → <kbd>Install another version...</kbd>, and select an appropriate version (e.g. `v2022.8.0` supports Python 3.6).

[image: The options cog is at the bottom-right of the extension.]